# Are there any ocsigen book available?

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen

Now we have used ocsigen successfully to host an old python cgi application. However, we need to study ocsigen in detail to decide whether or not using OCaml language to develop new web application.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: z_axis, I really like your questions about OCaml. I just have one suggestion for you. Accept answer even if you don't get the answer you want. This is because a lot of questions you ask tend to be open ended questions given the state of OCaml language and development at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, there is no book (but the online documentation is quite good).

And the people behind Ocsigen are quite nice people and will answer questions on their mailing list.